# How to pass parameter through views and controllers?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a model `Project` which have many `Order`s. On the page of the project, I have a list of its orders and create/update buttons. 
Now I pass `project_id` in GET params in url. I need watching that each url and redirect have this parameter (in the update and create views/controllers and in the list of orders view/controller).
Is there a better way, to pass parameter through views and controllers?

Comment: Are you using a framework ? Can you post some code please?

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Yii2, but it doesn't matter because this problem I have in other frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with MVC. In a web context, each HTTP request must be self-contained. All the information your server needs to fulfil the request must be contained within the request. Either within the URL, or within the request body.*

Whenever your server generates a URL somewhere to send back to the client, you need to embed all the information necessary in that URL so a request made to that URL gives your controller all the information it needs to fulfil the request. So, yes, you'll need to pass all the information through to that place in your code. That's pretty much the same whether you use MVC or plain spaghetti PHP files.

The only alternative is for you to reduce the amount of information the controller needs to fulfil the request, e.g. because you can implicitly get one part of information from another, like the project id when given just an order id.

* <sub>(I'll forego something like session storage here, since that's stateful across all requests and generally cannot be used for transporting information specific to individual requests.)</sub>